# Adding item to array in child object of a child object via reducer

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I apologize if my terminology is incorrect.  I am very new to reactjs and react-redux (couple days).

The challenge I am trying to overcome is adding an item in store.order.cart.items.  My store structure is as such:

```
{
    order:
        cart:
            items: [
                {name: "product a"},
                {name: "product b"}
            ]
}
```

My reducer is as follows:

```
import ApplicationState from '../application-state';
import { ADD_PRODUCT } from "../constants/action-types";

const initialState = ApplicationState;

const rootReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {

  switch (action.type) {
    case ADD_PRODUCT:
        return {
            ...state, order: {
                ...state.order, cart: {
                    ...state.cart, items: [
                        ...state.items, action.payload
                    ]
                }
            }
        };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default rootReducer;
```

My action for ADD_PRODUCT is as follows:

```
import { ADD_PRODUCT } from "../constants/action-types"

export const addProduct = product => ({ type: ADD_PRODUCT, payload: product });
```

And my action type constants (constants/action-types):

```
export const ADD_PRODUCT = "ADD_PRODUCT";
```

When I dispatch my addProduct action (testing this via the browser console: `store.dispatch( addProduct({ name: "product c" }) )`

I get the following error:

```
app.js:36995 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
    at Function.from (/native)
    at _toConsumableArray (app.js:36995)
    at rootReducer (app.js:37009)
    at Object.dispatch (app.js:13839)
    at <anonymous>:1:7
```

What am I doing wrong?  What is the correct way to get the new item added to the order.cart.items array?

Comment: Can you show `"../constants/action-types"`?

Comment: @acdcjunior I have added this to my post.  Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
items: [
  ...state.items, action.payload
]
```

In this excerpt above, you have attempted to spread `...state.items` into the items array, but items is actually at `state.order.cart.items`;

Similarly:

```
cart: {
  ...state.cart, 
}
```

`cart` is actually at `state.order.cart`

Deeply nested situations like this are why it's best to flatten your state where possible and use `combineReducers()`. Alternately you could look at an immutability helper to help with immutably setting deeply nested state

Comment: Thank you!  This makes sense and helps tremendously.  I'll also look into combineReducers() and an immutability helper